# Splitting a list into two lists in scala

Tags: list, scala, split, functional-programming, predicate

I have a list containing something like:

```
val lines: List[String] = List("bla blub -- id_1", "sdkfjdf -- id_2", "blubber blab -- id_1", "foo -- id_3", "ieriuer -- id_2", "bar -- id_3")
```

So basically the list contains an identifier which exists exactly twice (id_x) and a string which belongs to one of the identifiers.

I want to split that one list into two lists which then each contains a unique set of id_s with their belonging strings, like this:

```
l1("bla blub -- id_1", "sdkfjdf -- id_2", "foo -- id_3") 
l2("blubber blab -- id_1", "ieriuer -- id_2", "bar -- id_3")
```

How would i do that in a functional way?

Best Regards,
Sven

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lines.groupBy(_.split(" -- ")(1)).toList.map(_._2).transpose
```

That's the rough and ready way to do it; in reality if you want to do something more with this data it'll probably be better to parse the items into a case class, a la:

```
case class Item(id: String, text: String)
val items = for {
  line <- lines
  Array(text, id) = line.split(" -- ")
} yield Item(id, text)
```

then do the same as above, except `groupBy(_.id)`, and conveniently `sortBy(_.id)` as well.

Comment: That works, thank you very much, i didnt know about transpose. However, do you know about a version which could be parallized on the list?

Comment: `lines.par.groupBy ...` should do the trick. Not guaranteed to be faster though, especially for small lists.

Answer (score 1):

How about this solution?

```
lines.groupBy(_.takeRight(3)).map(_._2).foldLeft((List.empty[String], List.empty[String])) { 
  (acc, elem) => elem match {
    case left :: right :: Nil =>
      (left :: acc._1, right :: acc._2)
    case Nil => acc
  }
}

res2: (List[String], List[String]) = (List(bla blub -- id_1, sdkfjdf -- id_2, foo -- id_3),List(blubber blab -- id_1, ieriuer -- id_2, bar -- id_3))
```